# Power Query - Add table column by iterating through external query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a dataset called Risks which contain risk items that need to be categorised. In this query, there is a column called 'string' which is a singular string containing all the text in the risk item. I also have a "dictionary" table called Dictionary which contains two columns. Column 1 is 'category' and column 2 is 'key_words' and contains key words that would indicate the category to which a risk should be assigned. I need to calculate a new column in the Risks query that iterates through the dictionary table to see if the column 'string' in the Risks table contains the key word. If it does, the new column should return the category from the dictionary column 1.

How can I do this?

Data is as below:

Risk Query:

[image: [Risk Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5QZM.png)]

Dictionary Query:

[image]

Thanks

I was originally using python outside of PowerBI to do this however I now need to run the process inside PowerBI as I am using mutiple data sources. I am unable to use python inside of PowerBI due to difficulties hosting the final solution

Comment: Please post future questions input data as text, not images, to make helping you less of a burden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you find items in Risks with text from Dictionary using M

```
//code for Risks query
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source,"Category",(x)=>Text.Combine(List.Distinct(Table.SelectRows(Dictionary, each Text.Contains(x[description],[key_word],Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))[category]),","))
in #"Added Custom"
```

[image]

It loops through each row of Dictionary, finds all rows where dictionary is contained within Risks, pulls the category row, makes that unique, combines them with commas if there are more than one

Comment: Amazing, thanks a lot. Worked perfectly!